# How do you reopen an active process?

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I have an executable file for starting up a game server and I use the command line to start the process. I'm not very knowledgeable with the command line so I don't know what it's called, but basically, the command I use starts the server process and it "stays open" in the command window. So as long as I have the window open, I can use commands specific to that executable file. In order to close the process in the command line, I have to press CTRL + C. When I close the window, the process is still running, but I don't know how to go back to the process to do the executable specific commands. I don't know how to "open" the process that is currently running, if it's even possible.

So... is it possible? If I close the command line, can I still somehow return to the "open" state the executable was in before I closed the command line window?

Comment: Short answer: You can't with `cmd`.

Comment: @DavidPostill Well dang... what about powershell, though? I just remembered I have that option as well, would it be possible there? Updated tags.

Comment: Not easily. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43914800/attach-to-running-program-with-powershell

Comment: some apps will detect an existing instance when you run them ... and connect to that instance. have you tried that yet?

Comment: So, do can provide the executable name? How we can try answer without reproduce the scenery?...

Comment: I agree with @ItWasn'tMe, knowing what the application is and the use case will allow us to advise possible solutions. As you have specified game server there may be alternatives to allow you to pass commands to the server without the need to reattach to the console session itself (RCON being an example).

Comment: @CraftyB I mean, I don't know, I didn't want to specify because I hoped whatever answers I would get could help other people with whatever executable they had, so the answers wouldn't have to be specific to my executable. The executable I'm referring to is teeworlds_srv.exe, obviously from Teeworlds, if that helps.

Comment: @noClue - I understand where your coming from however with my experience of game servers not one solution will fit all in this sense. Unfortunately windows does not have a program similar to Screen in Linux which is ideally what you are looking for. However it does appear that you can access the console in game, please see this link - [TeeWorld Server Setup](https://www.teeworlds.com/?page=docs&wiki=server_setup) under section "Remote console".

Comment: @CraftyB I don't know if that's the best solution for me, as I want to have access to the instance I created on the command line level, but I'll take a look at it. Thanks.